# How to provide custom time to travel between the locations?

Tags: java, jsprit

I have 2D array of distances between geo-locations . see the link
[Map box time to travel](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#distance)

How do I inject this to build the problem in jsprit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this  :

```
VehicleRoutingTransportCostsMatrix.Builder vrtcMatrix;
VehicleRoutingTransportCostsMatrix costsMatrix;
vrtcMatrix.addTransportDistance(String.valueOf(fromId), String.valueOf(toId),
                                (double) distance.inMeters);
vrtcMatrix.addTransportTime(String.valueOf(fromId), String.valueOf(toId),
                                (double) duration.inSeconds);
costsMatrix = vrtcMatrix.build();
```

Then

```
VehicleRoutingProblem.Builder vrpBuilder = VehicleRoutingProblem.Builder.newInstance();
    vrpBuilder = vrpBuilder.setRoutingCost(costsMatrix);
```

You have to set it between all of your combinaison of points.
Use a distance matrix calculator to get a good distance/time estimation.

Hope it helps.